# how to get value from a range with last row and set value last row in different sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, setvalue, getvalue

I am trying to getvalue from one sheet and set value in another sheet. But i would like to only get value from L3 to AE lastrow. Setvalue to lastrow from col B in another sheet. Please help.

Below script copy everything and paste everything. Please help

```
function shipmentsubmit() {
  var sm        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entrySM    = sm.getSheetByName("ENTRY SHIPMENT"); //START entry Sheet
  var dataSM = sm.getSheetByName("SHIPMENT LIST2"); //START Sheet
  var values = entrySM.getRange("ENTRY SHIPMENT!3:" + entrySM.getLastRow()).getValues();
  values = values.filter(e=>e[12]); //gets rid of blank rows. filters based on the first column (index 0).
  dataSM.getRange(dataSM.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function shipmentsubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("ENTRY SHIPMENT");
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("SHIPMENT LIST2");
  var values = sh1.getRange(sh1.getLastRow(), 3, 1, sh1.getLastColumn() - 2).getValues();
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: i changed the script and run it but nothing happen. Plz help